# Switching off the middle click with the mouse button

Tags: keyboard, mouse, lenovo-laptop

I had the "Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB keyboard with trackpoint" keyboard. When I wanted to rewind the page, content in the text editor, positions in Filezilla, clicked the Wednesday button "mouse" and scrolled the content via TrackPoint.
And so it should be. It was good.

I replaced the keyboard for the second generation of "Lenovo ThinkPad Trackpoint II US 4Y40x49521".

I have a problem. When I do the same activity (I click the middle button "mouse" and scroll), first clicks (opening a new link, a new window, a new link in the card), then the page in Firefox scrolls. At Filezilla, I can't use the selection of FTP connections - the scrolling interrupts the launch of TrackPoint and opens a new connection.

How to get rid of unnecessary clicking with the "mouse" button (I don't want to turn off this key) and immediately move on to scrolling content? I want to continue to open the "mice" links in the new tab.

In addition, the central mouse button sticks me content for the text of the text. It's bad.
I trie
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=79088#p790888

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xmousepasteblock-git

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24330/how-can-i-urn-off-middle-mouse-button-paste-functionality-in-all-programs/472464##46464

For me, these solutions do not work

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to update to `kernel 5.19` and load the `hid-lenovo` kernel module.

Kernel module: https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_hid_lenovo

Support for Lenovo ThinkPad Trackpoint Keyboard II only landed in kernel 5.19: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/547#note_1379498

Now the unwanted pasting when clicking the middle button is gone and I can even scroll horizontally with the TrackPoint! \o/